# Javascript callback and google maps api question

Tags: javascript, callback, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api v3 and have an array of arrays object:

```
MVCArray.<MVCArray.<LatLng>>
```

I want to iterate over this.  I see that MVCArray has a method `forEach` which uses a call back, but I have no idea how to use this (I haven't done much js).  The api defines this method as follows:

```
forEach(callback:function(*, number)))
```

Could somebody please show me an example of how to use this given an MVCArray of MVCArrays (I need to pull out each LatLng object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can pass around functions in the same way you can pass around any other sort of data. There are two usual ways of approaching this.

First, you could define a function in the usual way and give it a name:

```
function myHappyFunction(item, index) {
   // Do things using the passed item and index
}
...forEach(myHappyFunction);
```

Here you're passing the function you've created into the forEach function. `myHappyFunction` will now get called a bunch of times, each time passing a different item from the list.

Alternatively, you can avoid the need to come up with a clever function name by just passing a function DIRECTLY, like so:

```
...forEach(function(item, index) {
    // Do things using the passed item and index
});
```

This behaves the same way, but without the need to develop a unique name for each and every function you might want to pass around.

Answer (score 1):

just to clarify @VoteyDisciple's answer, here is a real life example

aMarker is the MVCArray object which, by default, has draggable set to false. so when the user switches to 'true', my code calls this:

```
aMarker.forEach(function(item, index) {
    aMarker[index].setDraggable(true);
});
```

and makes them draggable.